# Powershell script for URL MONITORING

Tags: powershell

I have developed a powershell script which monitors the url continuously and triggers a mail when the url goes up / down. However, it doesn't display the url in the mail it triggers.

Code :

```
   Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions

  function Send-Mail([string] $url, [switch] $serverDown) {


$PSEmailServer    = ""
$smtpPort         = "25" 
$mailFrom         = "sender@my.mailserver.com"
$mailTo           = "recepient@mail.com"
$messageSubject   = "Web monitoring notification"

if( $serverdown.IsPresent ) {

    $body = @"
        <p>Hello,</p>
        <p>Server $($url) is reported down at $(Get-Date)</p>
"@
}
else {

$body = @"
        <p>Hello,</p>
        <p>Server $($url) is reported up again at $(Get-Date)</p>
 "@
  }

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $PSEmailServer -From $mailFrom -To $mailTo -Subject $messageSubject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -Port $smtpPort 
  }

     # ---------------- MAIN ------


 $url            = 
 "https://www.google.com"
  $errFlag        = $false
 $formerErrFlag  = $false
 $requestSeconds = 60

  while( $true ) {

try {
    $result        = Invoke-Webrequest -Uri $url -Method GET 
    $errFlag       = $false
}
catch [System.Net.WebException] {                              # e. g. error 500
    $responseBody = $_.Exception
    $errorDetails = ''
    $errFlag      = $true
}
catch {
    $result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result)
    $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
    [void]$reader.DiscardBufferedData()
    $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd()
    $errorDetails = $_.ErrorDetails.Message
    $errFlag      = $true
}


Send-Mail -url $url -serverDown:$errFlag

$formerErrFlag = $errFlag

Start-Sleep -Seconds $requestSeconds          # wait till next request
  }
```

Output : Hello,
Server is reported up again at 12/03/2019 03:34:30

Expected output : Hello,
Url (https://www.google.com) is reported up again at 12/03/2019 03:34:30

Few more questions :

1. The code is going to "else" part only, it's not checking the "if" condition.
2. Is it possible to invoke multiple url's in the same script.

Comment: Hi Bacon, Thanks for the reply... Apologies for missing out on first line. I have updated my code. Please have a look

Comment: Does it work if you change the beginning of the function to `function Send-Mail([string] $url, [switch] $serverDown) {` with no `param()`?

Comment: Hi Bacon, Thanks a lot. The first issue is resolved. I am getting the output as expected but still the second issue persists.Can you please have a look int it.

Comment: I'm not sure.  Your `$errFlag`/`$formerErrFlag` logic seems like a sound way to only report a change in status, though you might initialize `$formerErrFlag` to `$null` or not at all otherwise on the first iteration if `$errFlag` ends up `$false` it won't detect that as a change.  Debugging/displaying the values of those two variables might shed some light on this.  You might change `if( $errFlag ) { ... } else { ... }` to just `Send-Mail -url $url -serverDown:$errFlag` and `if( $serverdown ) {` to `if( $serverdown.IsPresent ) {`, but neither of those should cause the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Hi Bacon, I modified the code as suggested but still I am not getting the output as expected. Even if the url is up it says that the url is down. Please see the modified code.

Comment: `Send-Mail -url $url -serverDown:$errFlag` should have replaced the `if( $errFlag ) { ... } else { ... }` but still be _inside of_ the `if( $errFlag -ne $formerErrFlag ) { ... }`, otherwise it will send an email every time it polls the server whether the status has changed or not.  Still, that wouldn't cause the false negatives you're seeing, and might actually be fine for debugging purposes.  The only other thing I can see is the parameter is defined as `[switch] $serverDown` (uppercase `D`) yet you are testing `$serverdown.IsPresent`, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I tried your code and found that the server is always reported as _up_.  This is because, when the host doesn't exist or respond, in the second `catch` block the line `$result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()` throws an exception because the `Response` property does not exist, therefore `$errFlag` never gets set to `$true` and that affects the call to `Send-Mail`.  The simple fix is to set `$errFlag` at the _beginning_ of the `catch` blocks, but, better yet, avoid doing anything that might cause an error in a `catch` and check that `$_.Exception.Response` exists before accessing it.

Comment: Bacon, I tried every possibilities suggested by you, but no success. Also, the server is always reporting down not up.

Comment: How are you testing this script?  In a regular PowerShell session?  Are you able to see any errors the script might produce?  At this point I would recommend stepping through it with a debugger, or at least adding diagnostic output so you can see what it's doing.

Comment: I am running the program in Powershell editor and it's not throwing any error. I tried almost all the options but no success.